# How can i get short path from folder directory Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

i have some path's that i get from folder when i drop in my program but i want to start the path from where the program located.

im putting the program inside the desktop and drag and drop my folder call "Folder" into my program and getting full path and i want get only from where the program is located.

for example:

```
what i want:
tools\test.exe
tools\test2\test.exe

normal:
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Folder\tools\test.exe
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Folder\tools\test2\test.exe
```

my code:

```
Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)

        For Each path In files

            For Each Dir As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)

                ListBox1.Items.Add(path)

            Next

        Next
```

Comment: Q: Do you want just the parent directory?  That's easy: [Directory.GetParent(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```vb
Dim relativePath = fullPath.Substring(Application.StartupPath.Length + 1)
```

The 1 is added to remove the slash that I don't think is included in `Application.StartupPath`.

Comment: What do you suppose a variable named `fullPath` represents? Here's a clue: the code declares a variable named `relativePath` that is assigned a `String` that contains a relative file path that is a substring of `fullPath`. Given that the whole point of this thread is to get a relative path from a fully-qualified path, I assumed that it would be fairly obvious what something named `fullPath` represented.

Answer (score 0):

Try below line of code:

```
Dim relpath=System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
Dim relPath = fullPath.Substring(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory.Length + 1)
```